# DBD::SQLite issue with I/O errors over mounted filesystem

Tags: perl, sqlite

Consider the following Perl code:

```
#!/usr/env/ perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $filename = 'moo.sqlite';
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$filename","","");
my $sql = 'INSERT into moo values (1)';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
my $rv = $sth->execute();
print $rv;
```

produces this error when run:

```
DBD::SQLite::db prepare failed: disk I/O error at test.pl line 16.
Can't call method "execute" on an undefined value at test.pl line 18.
```

The SQLite file is located on a SMBFS/CIFS network mounted share.

I have done some tracing and it appears that the failure occurs when a lock is attempted on the file:

```
open("moo.sqlite\0", 0x202, 0x1A4)       = 3 0
fcntl(0x3, 0x1, 0x0)         = 0 0
fcntl(0x3, 0x2, 0x1)         = 0 0
```

While I understand that network locking is problematic, wouldnt the same problem occur when interactively running the 'sqlite3' binary? Currently, I am able to work on the file with no problems when I do so.

Is this something that DBI is causing?

For your info:

- OS OS X 10.6.8
- SQLite version 3.7.13
- Perl 5.12.4
- DBI 1.622
- DBD::SQLite 1.37

Comment: Do you get the same locking syscalls when using the `sqlite3` tool?

Comment: Yes, the calls are the same as far as I can see. Only difference is that the tool obtains the lock and then goes on and creates the SQLIte journal file in the same directory.

Answer (score 2):

> SQLite allows multiple processes to have the database file open at
>   once, and for multiple processes to read the database at once. When
>   any process wants to write, it must lock the entire database file for
>   the duration of its update. But that normally only takes a few
>   milliseconds. Other processes just wait on the writer to finish then
>   continue about their business. Other embedded SQL database engines
>   typically only allow a single process to connect to the database at
>   once.

You could try this, it may help:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$filename","","", "", "", {
  sqlite_use_immediate_transaction => 1,
});
```

the problem is that CIFS driver could be configured to honour/allow locking. If that part is not configured correctly, the locking will not work.

You could try to change the locking settings in samba: http://oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch05_05.html

The best candidate to try it out: "fake oplocks = yes"

If it is not working you could try to setup an ODBC datasource on the windows machine and access the database through that.

Comment: Thank you for your input. It's definitely a locking issue. I will try the suggested DBI parameter and let you know.